# Why does this code print big values instead of the totals I expect?

Tags: c

I'm trying to get 5 integer outputs and display odd count, even count, odd total and even total.  This code gives me bigger total values.  What's the problem?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int n,count,oc,ec;
    float ot,et,answer;

    for(count=0;count<=5;count++){
        printf("enter a odd or even number :");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }
    answer=n%2; 
    if (answer>0){  
        oc=oc+1;
        ot=n+ot;
    }

    else {
        ec=ec+1;
        et=n+et;
    }
    printf("odd counter is %f",oc);
    printf("odd counter is %f",ot);
    printf("even counter is %f",ec);
    printf("even counter is %f",et);
}
```

Comment: Read about `printf` and the format specifiers. You are not using them correctly. Also your variables are uninitialized when used.

Comment: If you are new to programming, why don't you start with Visual Basic?

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Hm. I would go with Python....

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Probably because he wants to learn about, you know, programming?

Comment: Did you compile this with warnings on?

Comment: Think about the fact that your for loop is storing a value and replacing it at each turn. Think of doing the job inside your for loop.

Comment: @FelixPalmen, VB is a perfectly suitable language for many tasks. And it learns you how to program. C is like a chain saw in programming; you can do anything with it but has a steep and long learning curve.

Comment: If you compile with warnings the compiler will warn for reading variables before assigning them. Try initializing `ot`, `oc`, `et` and `ec` to `0 `.

Comment: what's your reasoning behind using `float`s?

Comment: Note: `for(count=0;count<=5;count++)` does not "get 5 integer outputs" but 6.

Comment: You are supplying `int oc` and `int ec` as parameters for `%f` format which is expecting `double` (or `float` which will be promoted to `double`).

Comment: @PaulOgilvie even IF you prefer a language without UB for a beginner (apart from that, C is nice, clean, relatively small and logical, so I personally think, quite suitable) -- VB is the worst choice ever, IMHO.

Comment: @WeatherVane - actually, in the code he wrote he doesn't get 6 (or 5) inputs, he only gets one :)

Comment: You should add a newline to the end of each of the format strings in the `printf()` calls so that each output appears on a different line.  Or you need a space at the start of the second and subsequent calls so that the output is not all run together.

Comment: @KevinDTimm he gets 6 inputs. Each overwrites the last.

Comment: @WeatherVane - he gets an input 6 times - but leaves the loop with one value.  Also, note the :)

Comment: regarding: `for(count=0;count<=5;count++){
        printf("enter a odd or even number :");
        scanf("%d",&n);
    }`  this will overlay all the input values, so, in the end, the variable `n` will only contain the last value entered.  Also, always check the returned value from `scanf()`.  Suggest: `#define NUM_INPUTS 5  int n[ NUM_INPUTS ]]; for( count=0; count<NUM_INPUTS; count++ ) {
        printf("enter a odd or even number : ");
        if( 1 != scanf("%d",&n[ count ]) ) { fprintf( stderr, "scanf for  input %d failed\n", count ); exit( EXIT_FAILURE ); }`

Comment: "If you are new to programming, why don't you start with Visual Basic?" Horrible advise. "In programming indices start with 0. Except when they start with 1. Now write a program using arrays." Umm...

Comment: C is a very bad language to learn by trial&error. For other's it is just a bad idea. Get a good C book and work through the lessons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following proposed code:

1. cleanly compiles
2. properly checks for errors
3. has no undefined behavior
4. documents why each header file is being included
5. performs the desired functionality
6. uses no 'magic' numbers, 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 5.  See the `#define` and where the resulting (meaningful) name is being used.
7. handles each input, as it is input
8. uses text in the `printf()` statements that accurately says what the value being output actually means
9. uses proper formatting of each output value.
10. caveat: does not check for overflow of the summed values
11. properly writes the `for()` loop.
12. follows the axiom: *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*
13. uses appropriate horizontal spacing (for readability) inside parens, after commas, after semicolons, around C operators.
14. was compiled on linux using:
    `gcc -c main.c -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wconversion -std=gnu11 -o main.o`
15. was linked on linux using:
    `gcc main.o -o main`
16. was run using:
    `./main`

And now the proposed coded:

```
#include <stdio.h>   // printf(), fprintf(), stderr, scanf()
#include <stdlib.h>  // exit(), EXIT_FAILURE

#define MAX_INPUTS 5

int main( void )
{
    int n;
    int oc = 0;
    int ec = 0;
    int ot = 0;
    int et = 0;

    for( int count = 0; count < MAX_INPUTS; count++ )
    {
        printf("enter a odd or even number :");
        if( 1 != scanf( "%d", &n ) )
        { // then input error
            fprintf( stderr, "scanf for input %d failed\n", count+1 );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, scanf successful

        if ( (n%2) > 0 )
        {  // input was ODD
            oc = oc + 1;
            ot = n + ot;
        }

        else
        {  // input was even
            ec = ec + 1;
            et = n + et;
        }
    }

    printf( "number of odd inputs is %d\n", oc );
    printf( "sum of odd inputs is %d\n", ot );
    printf( "number of even inputs is %d\n", ec );
    printf( "sum of even inputs is %d\n", et );
}
```

the output of a typical run of the code:

```
enter a odd or even number :1
enter a odd or even number :2
enter a odd or even number :3
enter a odd or even number :4
enter a odd or even number :5
number of odd inputs is 3
sum of odd inputs is 9
number of even inputs is 2
sum of even inputs is 6
```

Answer (score 1):

Change your accumulators to integers and initialize them:

```
int oc, ot, ec, et;
oc = ot = ec = et = 0;
```

Move the closing brace as follows:

```
for(count=0;count<=5;count++){
    printf("enter a odd or even number :");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    answer=n%2; 
    if (answer>0){  
        oc=oc+1;
        ot=n+ot;
    }
    else {
        ec=ec+1;
        et=n+et;
    }
}
```

and change your printf's to use %d instead of %f

```
printf("odd counter is %d",oc);
printf("odd counter is %d",ot);
printf("even counter is %d",ec);
printf("even counter is %d",et);
```

Comment: And change your printf's to use %d instead of %f.

Comment: @DanKorn - edited